# I am stuck in the code for The Knight's Tour Problem

Tags: c++, backtracking

I wrote a code for The Knight's Tour Problem. It is running fine for 5 by 5 board but is stuck somewhere for 8 by 8 board. I am trying to resolve the issue since last 3 days. Seeking help here now, thanks!
Here is the link for question : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/the-knights-tour-problem-backtracking-1/

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;

bool isValid(ll x,ll y,vector<vector<int>> grid,ll n)
{
    if(x<0 || y<0 || x>=n || y>=n || grid[x][y] != -1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

bool solve(vector<vector<vector<int>>>& ans,vector<vector<int>>& grid,ll curr_num,ll x,ll y,ll n,vector<int> xi,vector<int> yi)
{
    if(curr_num>(n*n))
    {
        ans.push_back(grid);
        return true;
    }
    for(ll i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        ll nextx = x + xi[i];
        ll nexty = y + yi[i];
        if(isValid(nextx,nexty,grid,n))
        {
            grid[nextx][nexty] = curr_num;
            if(solve(ans,grid,curr_num+1,nextx,nexty,n,xi,yi)==true)
            {
                return true;
            }
            grid[nextx][nexty] = -1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    ll n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<vector<int>> grid(n,vector<int> (n,-1));
    vector<vector<vector<int>>> ans;
    vector<int> xi = {1,1,-1,-1,-2,-2,2,2};
    vector<int> yi = {-2,2,-2,2,1,-1,-1,1};
    ll curr_num = 2;
    grid[0][0] = 1;
    ll x = 0;
    ll y = 0;
    ll distinct = n*n;
    bool b = solve(ans,grid,curr_num,x,y,n,xi,yi);
    //Printing the answer
    for(auto& x : ans)
    {
        for(auto& y : x)
        {
            for(auto& z : y)
            {
                cout<<z<<" ";
            }cout<<endl;
        }cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can only imagine how hammered your memory controller is right now, making copies of the entire board with each check for a valid position, especially toward the latter half of the enumeration when more and more of them answer flat-no. Unrelated, whatever/whomever blessed you with the "competitive" boiler plate of garbage like `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` and `#define ll long long`, paddle away from them. All they're doing is honing your skill on writing crappy code quickly.

Comment: Looks like you are doing an exercise from a competitive coding site. Stop doing that if you want to learn C++. Get a C++ book, or use a site https://www.learncpp.com/ to teach yourself C++ first. And try to get a basic understanding of the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines). And then use those problems as fun puzzles to solve nothing more.

Comment: I think your code is correct, just **very** inefficient. There are some obvious steps to improve things (not passing vectors by value, and not passing global data at all) and some less obvious things (making the problem one dimensional and using sentinel values for the board edges) and some very clever things (basically traversing the search space in a smarter way). With the obvious steps done I was able to use your code to generate a tour of length 63 fairly quickly. I feel reasonably confident that if I'd left it running a full tour of all 64 squares would have popped out eventually.

Comment: You need a more cleverer solution; there are ~4×10^51 possible move sequences on an 8 × 8 board but only ~2.6×10^13 solutions, so you need to limit the search space by *a lot*. (You can find suggestions on the web.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks like it is correct, just inefficient.

```
bool isValid(ll x,ll y,vector<vector<int>> grid,ll n)
```

This will create a copy of the board on every call, which means a heap allocation. You should use `const vector<vector<int>> &grid`. You should start of always using `const ... &` for all arguments that aren't fundamental types and then reconsider when the compiler complains about something being `const`.

Another thing you can optimize is

```
if(x<0 || y<0 || x>=n || y>=n || grid[x][y] != -1)
```

That simple condition causes 5 branches and kills the branch predictor. A slight improvement is to eliminate the lazy evaluation on the first 4 conditions:

```
if((x<0 | y<0 | x>=n | y>=n) || grid[x][y] != -1)
```

Although compilers might think they are smart and still make that 5 branches.

A better way is to add a border to the grid and marking all the border as already visited. Then gird[x][y] can never go outside the bounds.

But more importantly than just speeding up the code in general is pruning the search tree. At the moment you try out move after move until you can move no more. But if you can decide earlier that a move can not result in a solution and prune the whole branch there you can save a lot of time.

Consider this situation (it's easiest to see for a corner but it applies to all fields):

```
########
########
##1+2+++
##+++3++
##+K++++
##+++4++
###+5+++
```

The Knight (K) has 5 moves it can make and you try all of them. But if you don't take move 1 then that means there is only one field left from which to reach 1. Field 1 must be the last field in the path. So the first time you see such a situation you can set a flag `have_last = true` and try out all 5 moves. But the second time you see such a situation (`have_last == true`) you must take move 1 and can skip 2-5. To do this for more than corners you have to add a second grid where each field says how many other fields can still this field and update/backtrack this for each move too.

This will allow you to avoid making moves that leave fields unreachable and prune the search tree considerably. Testing each move becomes more expensive but as long as it reduces the number of tests you make more than the cost increases it is a win.

Note: Instead of `have_last` you can also only look for paths that create a loop. In that case `have_last` would be true from the start and you can optimize it. Are there ever other solutions?

Note2: You start in the corner having 2 moves. Those two result in paths that are mirror images of each other. You can search just one and then mirror the found solutions.